# Getting the "main class not found" error when trying to launch any Java Program

Tags: java

I can't launch any .jar program since Java doesn't find the main class. This is true for ANY program not just my self written. So it isn't just a faulty manifest that is causing it. I have tried to just reinstall the Java runtime and JDK and also I have checked the PATH environment variables.
Java Runtime Version is "1.8.0_251" and JDK is "11.0.7".
Another Error I am seeming to get is an java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

I am trying to launch it via. "Java -jar C:...\Programname.jar" in the command prompt.

EDIT: So it is not applicable to any program.
For example: This is one of the programs that are working like intended:
http://www.softsea.com/download/Simple-Java-Calculator.html
However Programs like these ones are producing the errors mentioned:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/java-calculator/
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavacalculator100rc20jar.htm

EDIT2: I had also an OpenJDK installed which seemed to cause a conflict. I saw that the Path Variable of the OpenJDK got prioritized. Basically I have had different versions for java and the java compiler, even though they shared the same version number. This is at least my interpretation of the problem. For further judgment I am lacking experience with java and lacking depper knowledge about the processes in question. After I changed this my own programs are working at least. The example programs still do not work. I expect a problem on their side or some still underlying problem I am unable to identify. When trying to find working programs to test if your Java is working, I will definitely not choose random google results for "basic calculator java" next time.

I am thankful for your help, time and patience and I am sorry for any inconveniences I may have caused you trying to help me find the solution to my problem.

Comment: How are you launching them?

Comment: Are you sure it's true for *any* program? What jars have you tried to run? Also, make sure your `java` executable is also version 11.

Comment: I launching it via the command prompt and when I do "java -version" it shows as version "1.8.0_251" could that be the problem? Edit: Via changing the priorities of the envionment variables I now also have the version 11.0.7. But the problem still persists

Comment: @HattrickPat *"I launching it via the command prompt"* is not an accurate description of how you're doing it. **Edit** the question and show us the entire command you're running.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Go to the option of environment variables and add PATH in the user variables section by pressing new button.

For example, PATH C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin
Please use the version of your JDK in my case the jdk version is 1.80_191. It must match with the similar folder location

2. In the system variable section add new variable with name
   variable name: JAVA_HOME
   variable value: C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\lib
3. You must restart your computer after making changes to the environmental variables which is important.

Comment: 1) `JAVA_HOME` is not needed to run a Java program from the command prompt. --- 2) If PATH didn't have Java on it, the [`java -version` command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62816950/getting-the-main-class-not-found-error-when-trying-to-launch-any-java-program#comment111084875_62816950) executed by OP would have failed. --- Nothing in this answer is useful to the question.

Comment: I have triple checked my Path Variables and they are all set.

Comment: Well but the checking of the environment variables showed me actually an problem that was most likely the cause of this. Thank you for drifting my attention to those variables.